# How to get the effects to follow the object's animation?

Tags: animation, bones, smoke-simulation, makehuman

I'm using MakeHuman, `bvh` files and the smoke simulator. Just adding fire to the subject, fine tuning the fire, but when I run the animation, the fire does not stay attached to the subject when the `bvh` file kicks in.

How do I get the Domain to follow along with the moving subject in order to keep it burning like a person on fire moving around?

Comment: sounds like you need to do some motion tracking then apply an [object solver constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/motion_tracking/object_solver.html) to the fire domain.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar animation of a missile firing, and was struck with the same problem of moving the domain along with the particle effects emitter. I simply gave the domain the same path to follow as the missile. Remember that the larger your domain is, the larger the effects will be. If you keep the domain moving with the human by animating it to move with the human, you should have it fixed.